# Как преобразовать в строку ключи массива?

Tags: php, типы-данных

Несмотря на то, что явно указываю строковый тип для ключа массива все равно выводит эти ключи  в виде чисел без кавычек(посмотрите на 10-12-й ключи). Как исправить?

```
$monthes=[
          '01'=>'января',
          '02'=>'февраля',
          '03'=>'марта' ,
          '04'=>'апреля' ,
          '05'=>'мая' ,
          '06'=>'июня' ,
          '07'=>'июля' ,
          '08'=>'августа' ,
          '09'=>'сентября' ,
          (string)'10'=>'октября' ,
          (string)'11'=>'ноября' ,
          (string)'12'=>'декабря'
          ];
```

выводит

```
array(12) {
  ["01"]=>
   string(12) "января"
  ["02"]=>
   string(14) "февраля"
  ["03"]=>
   string(10) "марта"
  ["04"]=>
   string(12) "апреля"
  ["05"]=>
   string(6) "мая"
  ["06"]=>
   string(8) "июня"
  ["07"]=>
   string(8) "июля"
  ["08"]=>
   string(14) "августа"
  ["09"]=>
   string(16) "сентября"
  [10]=>
   string(14) "октября"
  [11]=>
   string(12) "ноября"
  [12]=>
   string(14) "декабря"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ключи массива - никак. Все выглядящие как целые числа ключи будут преобразованы в integer.

Это связано во-первых, с двойственной природой массивов РНР, которые одновременно и списки и хэши, а во-вторых - со свободной типизацией.

Числа в РНР всегда могут быть представлены как строки (а приходящие по протоколу НТТР всегда являются строками), и пользователь просто может не знать, подставляя индекс массива, число он добавляет, или строку:

```
$array = [1,2,3]; // у нас список, все ключи целые
$index = $_GET['index']; // ключ - строка "1"
$array[$index] = 5; // все ключи целые, все еще список
```

Если пхп не преобразует $index автоматом в целое, то массив из списка превратится в хэш. Это является той причиной, по которой ключи конвертируются в целое.

Почему пхп преобразовывает ключи, когда массив уже является хэшем - я не знаю. Думаю что для простоты и унификации.

Самое главное - это поведение очень редко представляет проблему. На моей памяти был только один случай, когда неверно работала сортировка по ключам массива.

Answer (score 2):

Немного дополню ответ @Ипатьев'а

Если массив не является упакованным (все ключи числовые и отсортированы по возрастанию и еще пара нюансов), то ключ хранится одновременно в виде строки и в виде числового хэша этой строки.

Строковые ключи хранятся в "корзине" хэш-таблицы одновременно как строка(key) и как ее хэш(h).

```
typedef struct _Bucket {
    zval              val;
    zend_ulong        h;                /* hash value (or numeric index)   */
    zend_string      *key;              /* string key or NULL for numerics */
} Bucket;
```

Для числовых индексов их значение хранится только в поле хэша(h), которое равно этому числовому индексу. Поле key при этом равно NULL.

Собственно вот как `var_dump` выводит элементы массива

```
static void php_array_element_dump(zval *zv, zend_ulong index, zend_string *key, int level)
{
    if (key == NULL) { /* numeric key */
        php_printf("%*c[" ZEND_LONG_FMT "]=>\n", level + 1, ' ', index);
    } else { /* string key */
        php_printf("%*c[\"", level + 1, ' ');
        PHPWRITE(ZSTR_VAL(key), ZSTR_LEN(key));
        php_printf("\"]=>\n");
    }
    php_var_dump(zv, level + 2);
}
```

Т.е. очевидно, что на этапе добавления элемента он посчитался за числовой.

`zend_vm_execute.h`, один из шаблонов функции добавления элемента `static ZEND_OPCODE_HANDLER_RET ZEND_FASTCALL ZEND_ADD_ARRAY_ELEMENT_SPEC_CONST_CONST_HANDLER(ZEND_OPCODE_HANDLER_ARGS)`

Нас интересует вот этот кусок:

```
        if (EXPECTED(Z_TYPE_P(offset) == IS_STRING)) {
            str = Z_STR_P(offset);
            if (IS_CONST != IS_CONST) {
                if (ZEND_HANDLE_NUMERIC(str, hval)) {    <<<<<<<<<
                    goto num_index;                      <<<<<<<<<
                }
            }
str_index:
            zend_hash_update(Z_ARRVAL_P(EX_VAR(opline->result.var)), str, expr_ptr);
        } else if (EXPECTED(Z_TYPE_P(offset) == IS_LONG)) {
            hval = Z_LVAL_P(offset);
num_index:
            zend_hash_index_update(Z_ARRVAL_P(EX_VAR(opline->result.var)), hval, expr_ptr);
```

Если рекурсивно раскрыть макрос `ZEND_HANDLE_NUMERIC`, то окажется, что он проверяет, является ли строка "числовой строкой". И если ответ положительный, то в массив добавляется элемент с числовым индексом вместо строкового. Такие дела.

Почему было принято решение делать именно так я не знаю, но предполагаю, что ради экономии памяти и ускорения за счет исключения расчета хеша строки(спорно).

Остается сказать, что менять такое поведения скорее всего никогда не будут, поскольку это повлечет за собой обратную несовместимость.

Comment: Познавательно, спс.